# JasperReports Server Dashboard hyperlink

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

So I linked my .jrxml file to the dashboard on jasperserver 3.0.
I have a hyperlink with the following coding:

```
<textField hyperlinkType="Reference">
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="111" uuid="c7641072-e10a-4edf-be4b-df32ee203078"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Click to goto Google"]]></textFieldExpression>
    <hyperlinkReferenceExpression><![CDATA["http://www.google.ca"]]></hyperlinkReferenceExpression>
    <hyperlinkTooltipExpression><![CDATA["click to goto google"]]></hyperlinkTooltipExpression>
    <hyperlinkParameter name="_report">
        <hyperlinkParameterExpression><![CDATA["/organizations/organization_1/reports/interactive/hyperlink_example"]]></hyperlinkParameterExpression>
    </hyperlinkParameter>
</textField>
```

I want the website to appear in the dashboard frame. But nothing loads as shown with the images attached.

Any direction would be appreciated.

Before click:
[image: before]

After onClick:
[image: after]

Comment: Did you check the generated link on page? You are passing parameter for opening `hyperlink_example` report.

Comment: Check whether you have `cross domain policy violation` error in the browser console.

Comment: Hello Viki and Alex, thank you for the replies. Okay,so I changed the parameter to the path of the dashboard and I set the hyperlink target to self and link type to reportexecution. When I run the dashboard example with the report linked in it. I get a error saying illegal value was used.Can you both exaplin how I can check the generated link on page and the crss domain violation?